# MVC Authenticate redirect to login with parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .net core 5 with an MVC Application.
In my Startup.cs, I have this code:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
           options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
           options.LoginPath = "/login";
        });
```

And, in my controllers, I put an [Authorize] annotation, which works perfectly.

But I have some MVC controllers that receive parameters, like:

```
  [Authorize]
  public IActionResult TestingView(string parameterA)
  {

  }
```

I would like that when the user tries to access the controller without being logged in. When he would be redirected to the login controller (the same as configured in Startup.cs), I would like the Login Controller to receive the ParameterA that he passed when he tried to access the TestingView controller.
This is because I need the parameterA inside the login controller to make some decisions.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your Login method, you can get `ReturnUrl`.

*Like below:*

```
https://localhost:44302/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/test/aa?aa=123
```

You can analysis the `ReturnUrl` to get the `parameterA`. This is the method with minimal code changes.